# Wordpress Concatenation Error

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, advanced-custom-fields

I am developed a wordpress site and i want to add a post type details in my template file.

the code is showed below,

```
query_posts('post_type=banner&orderby=menu_order&order=ASC&showposts=-1');
 if(have_posts()):
 while(have_posts()) : the_post();
     $img_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'my_thumb' ); 
     $url=get_the_permalink();
     $top_caption=the_field('top_caption');
     $bottum_caption=the_field('bottom_caption');

 $content_html .= '<div class="rotatorItem"> <img src="'.$img_url[0].'" class="fullImage" />
        <div class="caption">
          <p class="style1">'.$top_caption.'</p>
          <p class="style2">'.$bottum_caption.'</p>
        </div>
      </div>';
 endwhile;
 endif; wp_reset_query(); 
return $content_html;
```

I can getting the Image (featured image) successfully. but cant getting the Advanced custom fields. how can i concatenate this for use as a shortcode.

Anybody please help me.

Thanks

Comment: Concatenate for use as a shortcode? What?

Comment: <p class="style1">'.$top_caption.'</p> please give me the currect syntax for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `the_field()` which outputs the field. This means it can't be assigned to a variable. You need to switch to `get_field()`.

Example:

```
$top_caption = get_field( 'top_caption' );
```